# VBA Word -- formatting the color of a word depending on its first letter

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro that sets the color of each word in a document to a predefined color according to the word's first letter (e.g. if "a" = red, "apple" = red). This is to simulate a specific form of [grapheme-color synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme-color_synesthesia).

Here's an example what I currently have:

```
 Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "a"
    .MatchCase = False
    .Replacement.Text = "a"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .CorrectHangulEndings = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Replacement.Font.Color = a_color
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Obviously this just changes the color of each individual letter, not entire words.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or is there a way to find a selection based on its first letter?

Comment: it can be done, see my edited answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the macro I just recorded from the advanced search and replace "wizzard", this should work to find the first char:

```
.Text = "<a"
.MatchWildcards = True
```

< is "beginning of word", from the special characters list

To change the full word, it should then be this:

```
.Text = (<[aA]*>)
.MatchWildcards = True
.Replacement.Text = "\1"
```

Plus your code to change the color, and the rest of the code you already have. Assuming here that the upper case A gets the same color than the lower case.

After more tries, it appears you don't even have to give any replacement, and can get rid of the ():

```
.Text = <[aA]*>
.MatchWildcards = True
.Replacement.Text = ""
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an \0 available, to get all that was captured. Not needed here anyway. To do the search manually, http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm explains the menu in an extensive way.